# How do I add an entry in /etc/fstab for a windows share?

Tags: networking, mount, fstab

I want to be able to mount our file server's file share (on a Mac OS X server, shared via AFP and Windows File Sharing) on my Ubuntu 10.10 linux laptop. I want to be able to mount it as my normal user, and be prompted for the password each time. What do I add to `/etc/fstab` to make this happen? I know I did it before, but I forgot how now.

**EDIT:** The share in question is called "G4 320", and I am trying the following line in fstab:

```
//server_ip/G4\040320    /media/G4/    cifs    user,username=something    0    0
```

But I'm getting the following via `dmesg`:

> CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -6

**EDIT2:**

As requested, more debug info. Output of `dmesg` with my fstab line:

```
[151994.740138] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -6
[152007.760136] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -6
[152132.770147] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -6
[152221.700152] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -6
[152245.340132] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -6
```

Output of `dmesg` with the `credentials` line from Michael:

```
[153117.088656] CIFS VFS: No username specified
[153117.088668] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22
[153164.358300] CIFS VFS: No username specified
[153164.358312] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22
```

`/var/log/messages` seems to have no useful information.

**EDIT3**: OK. Thanks again to Michael I almost have it! If I put the following in `/etc/fstab` then it works:

```
//10.1.0.15/G4\040320H  /media/G4       cifs    user=AzureDiamond,password=hunter2       0       0
```

However:

1. I do not want my password in there...
2. I now need to use `sudo` to mount the share.

How can I resolve those two issues?

Comment: Can you please include additional log information? This can result from mount being unable to find the share, perhaps due to a naming error. If this were the case you should see a message similar to: `!!Mapping smb error code 67 to POSIX err -6 !!`

Comment: @Tok: Which log file(s) should I check? I posted more `dmesg` output but `/var/log/messages` has no relevant information...

Comment: Glad to see that things are moving forward. For reference, the dmesg log is where you want to be looking. If, in the future, you desire more verbosity try `echo 1 >/proc/fs/cifs/cifsFYI`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line in `/etc/fstab` I eventually used was:

```
//10.1.0.15/G4\040320H   /media/G4   cifs   username=master,user   0   0
```

What solved the issue of not being prompted for the password as well as `credentials=` not working was installing `mount.cifs` via:

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

Just like Michael Mrozek I assumed I had `mount.cifs` installed or else I wouldn't be able to mount CIFS shares, but apparently the kernel [will use it's own internal code](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1836/problems-mounting-an-smb-share-in-my-fstab) to mount unless it finds `mount.cifs`

Answer (score 2):

The filesystem is the Windows shared path, and the type is CIFS:

```
//file-server/ShareName /mnt/file-server-share cifs options 0 0
```

`options` can be all the usual mount options. You probably need to provide some sort of credentials; you can provide `user` and `password` options, or use `credentials=/path/to/credentials/file` and store `username=...` and `password=...` lines in that file (keep in mind that `/etc/fstab` is world-readable)

Comment: I tried `credentials=/home/myusername/.g4-credentials` and created `.g4-credentials` in my homedir (which is OK since I am using home directory encryption), but then I received the error "No username specified" via `dmesg`. Any idea on that vs return code -6?

Comment: @Josh What format is the file in? It should be "username=your-username" on one line, and "password=your-password" on another

Comment: Yup, that's exactly how it is...

Comment: @Josh Hmm. Well, I just noticed your question edit; the problem with your old way was `user` and `username` are synonyms; you need to pick one instead of listing both. `user=foo` is the CIFS way, but they allow `username=foo` for backwards-compatibility with SMBFS

Comment: @Michael almost there! See **EDIT3**, you were right, switching from `username` to `user` worked, but, broke user mounting...

Comment: @Josh I poked through my fstab to see how I did it, and confusingly I actually have it the way you had before; I used `user` to allow user mounts, even though the CIFS man page says that's not how it works. So I don't know how my fstab even works, but it seems like keeping `user` is correct after all. Maybe move it after `username=foo`?

Comment: Ah ha, the difference must be, I didn't have `cifs-utils` installed, and apparently [without that the kernel can't prompt for a password nor can it use credential files!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1836/problems-mounting-an-smb-share-in-my-fstab). If you add `apt-get` line to your answer I'll give you a shiny green **√** ;-)

Comment: @Josh Ah, nice. I didn't even know you could use cifs without `mount.cifs`. Just self-answer; you're the one who figured it out

Comment: Cool, thanks, I did. Just don't tell Rebecca, [she'll chastise me](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/397007#397007)! ;-)