# Mounting Windows shared folder with fstab

Tags: mount, fstab, cifs, shared-folders

I am trying to convert this command line:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.20.202/torrents /media/NAS -o username=x,password=y,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777
```

Into **/etc/fstab** entry, but it keeps mounting without 777 level of privileges.

So far I have this:

```
//192.168.20.202/torrents /media/NAS cifs uid=root,gid=root,username=x,password=y,0 0
```

Comment: A search on `fstab entry for Windows share` will yield some ideas. One that stood out to me was [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4879/286615) which resulted from discovery that `mount-cifs` may need to be installed? Doesn't seem likely in your case as apparently you're able to mount, but with wrong privileges, but I've learned that logic isn't always the best guide in `fstab` entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote:

```
//192.168.20.202/torrents /media/NAS cifs uid=root,gid=root,username=x,password=y,0 0
```

But you want to:

```
//192.168.20.202/torrents /media/NAS cifs username=x,password=y,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777 0 0
```